# Converting below logic without arrow function since it is not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert below logic with out arrow function since it is not working in IE

**I have converted getCellValue.**

```
const getCellValue = function(tr, idx){
    tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent
};
```

**I am not able to convert comparer const function and other logic.**

```
const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => (
    (v1, v2) => v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? 
        v1 - v2 : 
        v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
)(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    const table = th.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('.message-table:nth-child(n)'))
         .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
         .forEach(tr => document.getElementById("tblMsgBody").appendChild(tr));

    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('.show-documents:nth-child(n)'))
         .forEach(tr => {
             var elementId = tr.id.replace("document-handling-", "")
             $("#tr-" + elementId).after(tr)
         });
    })
));
```

Comment: What trouble are you having, exactly? What have you tried? Hint: you are probably getting stuck because arrow functions have an implicit return, so you may need to add a few return statements when converting back. But, you can do this all much more quickly with tools like Babel. See this emulator: https://babeljs.io/repl.

Comment: thanks for quick response

 I am getting an error in IE as "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'" at this line document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(function (th) {

Comment: Did you look up the NodeList forEach function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach. It's not supported in IE11. So what other logical structure can you use instead of `forEach`? Hint: it's a type of loop

Answer (score -1):

```
'use strict';

var comparer = function comparer(idx, asc) {
return function (a, b) {
    return function (v1, v2) {
        return v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);
    }(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
    };
};

document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(function (th) {
    return th.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var table = th.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('.message-table:nth-child(n)')).sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), undefined.asc = !undefined.asc)).forEach(function (tr) {
        return document.getElementById("tblMsgBody").appendChild(tr);
    });

       Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('.show-documents:nth-child(n)')).forEach(function (tr) {
            var elementId = tr.id.replace("document-handling-", "");
            $("#tr-" + elementId).after(tr);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Matthew,

I am getting an error in IE as
"Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'"
at this line
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(function (th) {

Comment: @Matthew, Note the section on "Answer Well-Asked Questions" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer